# How can you redescribe a curve so that the distance traveled is the same as the time interval?

Tags: calculus

If that doesnt make sense, let me know and I can try to clarify more.

Thanks.

Comment: make the velocity = 1. You can do it either by scaling time or scaling length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called [arc length parameterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization). It works for regular curves.

Comment: I thought that a function was an arc length paramterization for a curve C if the arc length is equal to b-a(the intervals in the integral). I dont understand how you can use this to redescribe the curve.

Comment: If you can calculate the the arc length $s$ from $a$ to $b$ as a function $s=\int_{a}^{b} |r'(t)|\, dt$ for time parameterization $r(t)$ describing the curve, we can then rewrite $t$ in terms of $s$, and plug $s$ into the original parameterization. Now if we let $s$ be the time changing instead of $t$, we get that a particle on the curve now moves a constant distance per unit of time, which is what you wanted if I understand correctly.